# Can I use a Domino server for proxying HTTPS requests?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

Using a Domino XWork Server (v9.0.1FP9), I would like to forward/proxy HTTPS requests of certain paths to other ports on the same server. For example: If someone requests

> https://www.example.com/app1/*

he should be served with the response from

> http://localhost:8081/*

The client/browser should not be notified about this, i.e. performing a 30x HTTP redirect by adding a website rule to the Domino server is not an option. Using a substitution website rule doesn't work either because it does not allow to change the port. I'm searching for a feature similar to Apache's ProxyPass or RewriteRule, but any working solution would be fine with me as long as the Domino server works as the proxy.

Does anybody know if/how this can be achieved with a Domino XWork server?

Comment: Why should Domino be the proxy? I would install an nginx server in front of Domino as a reverse proxy. That will give you all the flexibility you want in terms of redirecting/ proxying. This should get you started: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/6AF303DE836BA02D85257D570058B1CA

Comment: @MarkLeusink: I know I could set up an Apache or Nginx proxy in front of Domino, but I already have a Domino server running and would prefer using it instead of adding another element to the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Proxy Servlet wich does this job.

Here is an example https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give it a try.